# Create threads in loop and wait until all threads finished/aborted

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET console program in which I started 10 threads in a for-loop.
After the loop finished, the 10 threads will be running and I need the code to pause there (right after finishing the for-loop) until all threads are finished/aborted.

How can I do it?

Here is the example:

```
Private Sub TheProcessThread()

    While True

        'some coding
        If 1 = 1 Then

        End If

    End While

    Console.WriteLine("Aborting Thread...")
    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()

End Sub

Sub Main()

    Dim f as Integer
    Dim t As Thread
    For f = 0 To 10
        t = New Thread(AddressOf TheProcessThread)
        t.Start()
    Next

    ' HERE !! how I can be sure that all threads are finished/aborted for continue with the code below ?
    ' more vb.net code...
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not ever ever ever call `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()` **unless** you are trying to forcibly close your app. Calling `.Abort()` can put the .NET run-time in an invalid state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.  I made some modifications to your code but it is essentially the same.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim t As Task
    Dim l As New List(Of Task)
    For f = 0 To 10
        t = New Task(AddressOf TheProcessThread)
        t.Start()
        l.Add(t)
    Next

    ' HERE !! how I can be sure that all threads are finished/aborted for continue with the code below ?
    ' more vb.net code...    End Sub
    Task.WaitAll(l.ToArray) 'wait for all threads to complete
    Stop
End Sub

Private Sub TheProcessThread()

    While True

        'some coding
        If 1 = 1 Then
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            Exit While
        End If

    End While

    Console.WriteLine("Aborting Thread...")
    'Thread.CurrentThread.Abort() 'End Sub causes thread to end

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple and old-school, just use `Join()` like this:

```
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

    Private R As New Random

    Sub Main()
        Dim threads As New List(Of Thread)
        For f As Integer = 0 To 10
            Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf TheProcessThread)
            threads.Add(t)
            t.Start()
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting...")
        For Each t As Thread In threads
            t.Join()
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("Done!")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TheProcessThread()
        Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10001))
        Console.WriteLine("Thread Complete.")
    End Sub

End Module
```